# php, вывод в выпадающий список

Tags: php, html, html5

Добрый день. Имеется список (select). Скрипт должен распарсить имена php файлов в директории, затем вывести их в выпадающий список. И он выводит, но криво. Получается, что название каждого нового файла помещается в отдельный выпадающий список, а надо, что-бы в один.

```
$dir = '../';

$f = scandir($dir);

foreach ($f as $file){
    if(preg_match('/\.(php)/', $file)){

         echo '<select><option>'.$file.'</option></select>';

    echo'<br>';

    }

}
```

что я делаю не так ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так вы вынесите `echo '<select>` ЗА пределы цикла

```
$dir = '../';
$f = scandir($dir);
echo '<select>';
foreach ($f as $file){
    if(preg_match('/\.(php)/', $file)){
         echo '<option>'.$file.'</option>';
    }
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: спасибо, все впорядке, я просто краб

Comment: @qazqaz Бывает :)